# Comma before a clause starting with particle 'и'

Tags: пунктуация

Do I need а comma in the following sentence?:

> ...об этом там почему-то умолчано. **Не сказано также и что именно
>   имеется в виду под словом "объект"**.

It looks to me like a complex sentence with two clauses and naturally there should be a comma here, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. If you need a rule, the following might help:

> **§ 142.** При двух рядом стоящих союзах (подчинительный союз или относительное слово и другой подчинительный союз; сочинительный союз и подчинительный союз или относительное слово) запятая между союзами ставится только в том случае, когда опущение придаточного предложения не требует перестройки главного предложения.
>
> Если перед подчинительным союзом или относительным словом стоит отрицание **не** или сочинительный союз (**и**, **или** и т. д.), тесно сливающийся с придаточным предложением, то последнее не отделяется от главного запятой, например: Я хочу знать не как это делается, a зачем это делается. Он раздражителен и когда болен, и когда здоров.

Basically, if two conjunctions collide like that, you need to watch carefully if "excluding" the dependent clause from the sentence makes any sense. In your sentence "что" is directly connected to "и", so separating them would seem weird (it would suggest that "Не сказано также и." is a perfectly OK sentence).

Comment: What did you mean by "doubling as an object placeholder"?

Comment: "сказано" requires some object to "be said" (which is a grammatical subject, because it is a passive participle). On the second though, it doesn't matter here, so I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

In your example before the conjunctions что there is another conjunctions и. in this case we don't need comma.

Compare: Не вернул он мне книгу ***и когда*** прочитал ее; Скоро станет известно ***и кто*** приедет на праздник;

See: [Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134)

Comment: Are both "и" in your examples really conjunctions? Aren't they particles?

Comment: In my examples both "и" are really conjunctions.But this is not always the case. Sometimes there may be also participle in this position.

Comment: See the link in my main answer.

Comment: The link doesn't seem to specify exactly whether they are conjunctions or particles: "если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит сочинительный союз и (или частица):". In the following cases they аrе definitely conjunctions: "Он тебе книгу-то вернул?" - "Не вернул он мне книгу, и когда прочитал её, то даже не упомянул о ней", "А нам уже известно место праздника?" - "Скоро станет известно, и кто приедет на праздник мимо нас не пройдёт". And they are definitely particles here: "Не вернул он мне книгу и после того", "Скоро станет известно и имя его". As for yours, I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, the link doesn't specify exactly when they are conjunctions and when participles.  The book says there may be both conjunctions and participles in this positon.